# How do i sort nested dictionary based on value of first key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary in following format:

```html
{
 'Item1': {'Cl': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3'], 'Re': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']}, 
 'Item2': {'Cl': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3'], 'Re': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']}, 
 'Item3': {'Cl': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3'], 'Re': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']},
 'Item4': {'Cl': ['E2', 'E1', 'E3'], 'Re': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']}
 }
```

And i want to restructure in the following format:

```html
{
 'Item1': {'Re': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3'], 'Cl': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']}, 
 'Item2': {'Re': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3'], 'Cl': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']}, 
 'Item3': {'Re': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3'], 'Cl': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']},
 'Item4': {'Re': ['E2', 'E1', 'E3'], 'Cl': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']}
     }
```

I have tried sorted() but it doesn't seem to work or maybe i'm not implementing it in the correct way.

Comment: Why `pandas` tag?

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Comment: You just want to sort the keys?

Comment: @mozway yeah. Basically for each item (Item1,Item2...) i want Re (and its values) before Cl.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: @mozway The dictionary being nested is causing me issue

Comment: @Arkadiusz the dictionary being nested in my case is causing me issue

Comment: OK, I'll provide you with an example

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension. I am assuming here that you want to sort the keys by reverse lexicographic order:

```
{k:{k2:v[k2] for k2 in sorted(v, reverse=True)} for k,v in d.items()}
```

output:

```
{'Item1': {'Re': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3'], 'Cl': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']},
 'Item2': {'Re': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3'], 'Cl': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']},
 'Item3': {'Re': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3'], 'Cl': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']},
 'Item4': {'Re': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3'], 'Cl': ['E2', 'E1', 'E3']}}
```

If you want to push 'Re' to the beginning, and keep the rest in the same order (assuming more than 2 keys), you could do:

```
{k:{k2:v[k2] for k2 in sorted(v, key='Re'.__ne__)} for k,v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be using an `OrderedDict` or the like to guarantee that insertion order is remembered no matter the Python implementation?

Comment: @LMD dictionaries are maintaining insertion order since python 3.7 ([part of spec](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html), not implementation detail) ;)